# Windows Phone 8 app doesn't run on emulator when is under git control

Tags: .net, git, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I have an issue with Windows Phone 8 emulator. When my project is under git control I can't run it on emulator. After when I run Emulator WVGA 512 MB in Visual Studio 2013, emulator turns on but VS shows me an error:

```
There were deployment errors. Continue?
```

In output window:

```
1>------ Deploy started: Project: DataBoundApp1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Deploying C:\Users\Martin\Source\Repos\IC%202014\DataBoundApp1\DataBoundApp1\Bin\Debug\DataBoundApp1_Debug_AnyCPU.xap...
1>Connecting to Emulator WVGA 512MB...
1>Installing the application...
1>Deployment of application to device failed.
1>The parameter is incorrect.
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

When I move solution folder outside of the git repository, it works fine without any errors. It is a solution created from standard VS template. I didn't make any changes in files.

What is the reason of such strange behavior? How can I fix it?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue. The main reason of this behavior was name of the folder. I changed name from `IC%202014` to `IC 2014` and after that it runs correctly. Probably percent sign in path is prohibited by emulator.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever I come across a weird situation like the one you experience, I always try to do a "Clean and Build" before anything else. It solves a lot of issues.

Comment: I've tried to clean and build but it doesn't solve problem. Restart VS and Windows also changes nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and installing [Windows Phone SDK 8.0 Update 3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=41559) and choosing "Emulator 8.0 Update 3 WVGA 512MB" did work. Unfortunately the non-update 3 version still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware the OP had problems with Emulator, but I came across this issue on the real device recently, so this might be useful for someone as well.

I was trying to deploy two applications from two instances of Visual Studio (2012+2013) on the same device. Although the one from VS2013 had no problem, the other one from VS2012 threw the `"Parameter is incorrect"` error.

Rebuilding the project did not help, but it turned out that the easy way to fix this issue was just to unplug the phone for a moment and then deploy the second app again.

**EDIT:**

On the other hand, if I run the 2012 project first and then try to run the 2013 one, the Visual Studio 2013 console reads:

```
>The application is already installed on the device. Checking if an incremental deployment is possible...
>Doing incremental deployment...
>Updating information related to modified files...
>Deployment of C:\projects\Win8\MyApp\bin\ARM\MyApp-Debug\MyApp-Debug_ARM.xap succeeded.
```

and then a message box is displayed with a better understandable error:

[image: Visual Studio 2013 Error Message]

Again, unplugging the phone for a short while and performing another deployment (Run) is enough to bypass this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that the `.appx` file was in a shared location.  As soon as I copied it to my computer the error disappeared.